# How to insert records using the Entity Manager without defining the Primary Key field?

Tags: java, persistence, java-ee-6, entitymanager

I have trying to insert a record into the database (MySQL), using Entity Class and Entity Manager. But one of the field is an auto incrementing primary key, so unless I provide an value manually, the insertion is not successful.

```
public boolean newContributor(String name, String email, String country, Integer contactable, String address) {
        Contributors contributor = new Contributors(); //entity class
        contributor.setId(??????); //this is Primary Key field and is of int datatype
        contributor.setName(name);
        contributor.setEmail(email);
        contributor.setCountry(country);    
        contributor.setContactable(contactable);
        contributor.setAddress(address);

        em.persist(contributor);
        return true;
    }
```

How to solve such problem? Is there a way to tell the entity manager to attempt the insert without the ID field and use `NULL` value instead.

***Update:*** Here is a portion of the entity class defining the `id`

```
...
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 50)
....
```

Comment: Is your `Contributors.id` field annotated with `@Id` and `@GeneratedValue`? If the key is autogenerated, you don't have to set it at all. But you need to `flush()` in order to retrieve genrated id.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz, This should be in the Entity Class right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell the entity manager to attempt the insert without the ID field and use NULL value instead?

Sure. You need to remove the `@NotNull` annotation for `id` field in the `@Entity` definition, and also remove the row:

```
contributor.setId(??????);
```

from method `newContributor()`. The reason for this is that the `@NotNull` annotation enforces a validation check in the JPA stack. It doesn't mean that the field is NOT NULL at a database level. See [here](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/BVAL-234) a discussion about this issue.

The rest of the code looks fine.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Could you please explains the reason too?

Comment: I'm looking for some references